# Prevent vim vertically split view resizing to 20 characters

Tags: vim

I have files that I am comparing side-by-side using the vertical split functionality in gvim, and am sizing them to 4-5 characters wide. Whenever I focus on one of these files, gvim automatically resizes the file view to 20 characters.

How do I disable this functionality?

NOTE: I am running vim 7.4.161 on Debian Jessie.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the split that you don't want to be resized you have to

```
:set winfixwidth
```

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but related to the topic, you can also `:set winfixheight` to lock the height of a particular split as well

Answer (score 7):

If you don't want vim to make splits equal everytime you split or switch to a window you can do the following:

```
:set noequalalways
```

Of course @René Nyffenegger solution of using `'winfixwidth'` works well too.

For more help see:

```
:h 'ea'
:h 'wfw'
```